# Printing a dictionary using .format in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format :-

```
d = { 'x' : 1, 'y' : 2, 'z' : 1, 'a' : 3 }
```

How can I print this to shell in the following format :-

```
 alphabet      number
----------------------
    a            3
    y            2
    x            1
    z            1
```

My code to print the dictionary to shell :- (ignoring printing 'alphabet,'number' and '-----')

```
for key,value in sorted(d.items()):
    print("{:>10}{:>20}".format(key,value))
```

So I know how to use the .format method to print the dictionary, but looking at the desired output I cannot understand how to print the dictionary by largest value to the smallest value.

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Look at the `key` argument of `sorted`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted and https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: It would be duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/2218718

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate like this:

```
for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
    print("{:>10}{:>20}".format(k, d[k]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be,

```
>>> d = { 'x' : 1, 'y' : 2, 'z' : 1, 'a' : 3 }
>>> for i,j in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print("{:>10}{:>20}".format(i,j))


         a                   3
         y                   2
         x                   1
         z                   1
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your method works too :)